# Shorten Length of String

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column in a table that has gotten some names in it that are too big for the website that it hooks up to.  Anything 50 or greater causes problems.  I have written this to try to shorten based on adding make + model + the four number year.  I am having a problem with the update inside the while loop.  Maybe I should be using a temp table and am approaching this completely wrong.  Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT *

FROM [Year] y

INNER JOIN Year_Model ym
ON y.YearId = ym.YearId

INNER JOIN Model m
on m.ModelId = ym.ModelId

INNER JOIN Make ma
on ma.MakeId = m.MakeId

--WHERE (len(m.name) + len(ma.name) + 4)>= 50

WHILE (len(m.name) + len(ma.name) + 4)>= 50
BEGIN
DECLARE @ModelId integer;
SET @ModelId = m.ModelId
DECLARE @NewModelName string;
SET @NewModelName = (Select Left(m.name, (len(m.name)-1))
UPDATE m
SET m.name = @NewModelName
WHERE @ModelId = m.ModelId
END
GO
```

Comment: This is T-SQL, right?

Comment: yes sorry, I should have added that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [Model] SET [name]=xx.ShortName
FROM 
(
    SELECT m.ModelID,LEFT(m.name,len(m.name)-1) as ShortName
    FROM [Year] y
    INNER JOIN Year_Model ym ON y.YearId = ym.YearId
    INNER JOIN Model m  on m.ModelId = ym.ModelId
    INNER JOIN Make ma  on ma.MakeId = m.MakeId
    WHERE (len(m.name) + len(ma.name) + 4)>= 50
) xx
WHERE xx.ModelID = [Model].ModelId
```

NOTE:  the LEFT should be 
**LEFT(m.name,len(m.name)-1)**

not the original 
**LEFT(m.Name,len(m.Name(-1)))**

But, run the inner query first to make sure you see the results you want, before you run the actual udpate...

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot find either column "m" or the user-defined function or aggregate "m.Name", or the name is ambiguous.  It looks good though.

Comment: Show me the exact query you have, sounds like a typo somewhere

Comment: USE ProfileData_10

 UPDATE [Model] SET [Name]=xx.ShortName
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT m.ModelId, LEFT(m.Name,len(m.Name(-1))) as ShortName
  FROM [Year] y
  INNER JOIN Year_Model ym ON y.YearId = ym.YearId
  INNER JOIN [Model] m  on m.ModelId = ym.ModelId
  INNER JOIN Make ma  on ma.MakeId = m.MakeId
  WHERE (len(m.Name) + len(ma.Name) + 4)>= 50
 ) xx
 WHERE xx.ModelId = [Model].ModelId

Comment: I ran a syntax checke on it, and it checked OK.   Can't really tell what the error is without the actual tables.   Look for a missing period (i.e. m or m, rather than m.    Sorry can't be of more help

Comment: `USE ProfileData_10

 UPDATE [Model] SET [Name]=xx.ShortName
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT m.ModelId, LEFT(m.Name,len(m.Name(-1))) as ShortName
  FROM [Year] y
  INNER JOIN Year_Model ym ON y.YearId = ym.YearId
  INNER JOIN [Model] m  on m.ModelId = ym.ModelId
  INNER JOIN Make ma  on ma.MakeId = m.MakeId
  WHERE (len(m.Name) + len(ma.Name) + 4)>= 50
 ) xx
 WHERE xx.ModelId = [Model].ModelId`

Comment: well that wasn't much better, sorry

Comment: Try putting [name] rather than just name wherever you reference the field Name

Comment: I revised the query, the code should be  LEFT(m.name,len(m.name)-1)

Answer (score 2):

Don't shorten anything.  You may need the complete names for something else.

You can use the t-sql left() function to select the first x characters.  Alternatively, you can select the entire name and use application code to format it as you see fit.

Comment: I wish I could do it that way, but it needs to be shorter in the Database.